# JS CLI RPS game issue

Tags: javascript, loops, scope, logic, command-line-interface

Greetings to the caring people of Stack Overflow.
I just recently started to learn JS and am now trying to make a CLI Rock Paper Scissors game. Yes, I know that I am the 100th person who has asked questions about it, but I could not find the 'no-make-sense' code through the code of other people. So just I ask for help from everyone who is not indifferent to helping a newbie!

The situation is this: the most common rules of a familiar game, but I can't get the counter to work, plus sometimes the text I type in is not recognized (I think the reason for the input comparison function).
Also, I'm sure that my func scopes are broken but where and why I can't figure out or trace it.

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let anyPick = Math.random();
  if (anyPick < 0.3) {
    return "Rock";
  }
  if (anyPick > 0.3 && anyPick < 0.6) {
    return "Paper";
  }
  if (anyPick > 0.6) {
    return "Scissors";
  }
}

let aiScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;
function battleRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
    return "None of you are win or lose, cuz it is an equal!";
  }
  if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
    playerScore += 1;
    return "You Win! Rock beats Scissors";
  }
  if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    aiScore += 1;
    return "You Loose! Paper beats Rock";
  }
  if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
    aiScore += 1;
    return "You Loose! Scissors cut Paper";
  }
  if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    playerScore += 1;
    return "You Win! Paper beats Rock";
  }
  if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    playerScore += 1;
    return "You Win! Scissors cut Paper";
  }
  if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    aiScore += 1;
    return "You Loose! Rock beats Scissors";
  } else return "U misspelled, try again";
}

function scores(aiScore, playerScore) {
  if (aiScore > playerScore) {
    return "CONGRAS, AI IS SMARTER THEN YOU!";
  }
  if (playerScore > aiScore) {
    return "CONGRAS, YOU ARE SMARTER THEN AI";
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const playerSelection = prompt(
    "Choose: Rock, Paper or Scissors",
    " "
  ).toLowerCase();
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();
  console.log("AI choose: " + computerSelection);
  console.log(battleRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
  console.log("AI score: " + aiScore, "Player score: " + playerScore);
}
```

Please, indicate an obvious problem in the code and what exactly I need to replace.
Much obliged for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There are two main problems with your code that might be causing this issue,

- **You are setting the default prompt value to an empty space.** By using:

```js
prompt("Choose: Rock, Paper or Scissors", " ")
```

The default prompt value is an empty space, making it easier to mistype the value.

To fix this, I removed the default value and added the [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) method to remove whitespace from the start and end of the input.

- **You are making impossible comparisons.** In your code you made the comparison:

```js
if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
     return ("None of you are win or lose, cuz it is an equal!");
}
```

This condition will never be `true`, as the `playerSelection` is always converted to lowercase e.g `"rock"`, but the `computerSelection`'s first letter is always uppercase e.g `"Rock"`.

I added the [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method to the end of `computerSelection` before comparing.

**Full code:**

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let anyPick = Math.random();
  if (anyPick < 0.3) {
    return "Rock";
  }
  if (anyPick > 0.3 && anyPick < 0.6) {
    return "Paper";
  }
  if (anyPick > 0.6) {
    return "Scissors";
  }
}

let aiScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;

function battleRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection === computerSelection.toLowerCase()) {
    return "None of you are win or lose, cuz it is an equal!";
  }
  if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
    playerScore += 1;
    return "You Win! Rock beats Scissors";
  }
  if (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    aiScore += 1;
    return "You Loose! Paper beats Rock";
  }
  if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "Scissors") {
    aiScore += 1;
    return "You Loose! Scissors cut Paper";
  }
  if (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    playerScore += 1;
    return "You Win! Paper beats Rock";
  }
  if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Paper") {
    playerScore += 1;
    return "You Win! Scissors cut Paper";
  }
  if (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "Rock") {
    aiScore += 1;
    return "You Loose! Rock beats Scissors";
  } else return "U misspelled, try again";
}

function finalScores() {
  if (aiScore > playerScore) {
    return "CONGRATS, AI IS SMARTER THEN YOU!";
  }
  if (playerScore > aiScore) {
    return "CONGRATS, YOU ARE SMARTER THEN AI";
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const playerSelection = (prompt("Choose: Rock, Paper or Scissors") ?? "")
    .trim()
    .toLowerCase();
  const computerSelection = computerPlay();
  console.log("AI choose: " + computerSelection);
  console.log(battleRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
  console.log("AI score: " + aiScore, "Player score: " + playerScore);
}

console.log(finalScores())
```

Comment: Thank you @lejlun for pointing out the nuances that I would have seen for a long time but did not know what exactly are the cause of the problems. But now the error appeared in the console:  [Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'prompt("Choose: Rock, Paper or Scissors")
      .trim')
 Global Code (scrip.js:57)

I don't quite understand why "null is not an object" to .trim ?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reproduce this with my code, is there anything that you've added or changed that could be causing this?

Comment: No, I haven't changed anything from the snippet you updated ... maybe it's in the browser, I'm using Safari.
Actually, this is not a problem, everything works as I intended except for the last peace.

Comment: @PavelPopok I've made an update to the post above, if `prompt` returns `null`  for whatever reason, an empty string will be returned instead. Please see if this fixes your error

Comment: @PavelPopok Your issue below is caused by the fact that your `finalScores` function does not output anything but instead returns silently. You can make your function output something by placing it inside of a `console.log` statement like I have above.

Comment: Wow, it works! I didn't really understand the syntax "?? """ but I will definitely go to the MDN and find out how you corrected it so succinctly. Thank you so much @ lejlun for the corrections and clarifications - you made my day!